Inability to delete comments in Chrome
I attempted to delete a comment while using Chrome, but clicking the delete symbol did not result in any noticeable response. I was able to successfully delete the comment using Firefox, and was also able to delete a comment on Math.SE using Chrome. However, I am still unable to delete comments on Crypto.SE while using Chrome. Is the problem widespread, and if so, is a fix possible?

Chrome 13 beta / Windows 7. I will try with 14.

No luck. I am still unable to delete comments. What's most curious is that I have no trouble deleting comments on any of the other SE sites that I have tried.

I saw this issue on chrome 12.0.742.122 on os x 10.6.7. It was deleting the comment, but not showing the comment being deleted. I refreshed the page and the comment was gone.

As I recall Chrome around this version started breaking some of its caching behavior.
If this is still an issue let us know, but I strongly suspect it was just Chrome at that time.

It is no longer an issue, thanks.
